# Rotating Iptables logs with logrotate

Tags: centos, iptables, logging, logrotate

I'm running CentOS6 and I configured rsyslog to monitor my iptables warning messages and dump them in `/var/log/iptables.log`. I went through my `logrotate.d/syslog` file and added `iptables.log` so logrotate would pick up and rotate the logs. The file looks like this:

```
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
/var/log/iptables.log
{
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

However, when I run `logrotate -f -v logrotate.conf` to trigger a force roll, the iptables.log file doesn't roll. To make logrotate not barf on the iptables file, I created a `iptables.log-20121014` file.

My output when I run the command looks like this:

```
rotating log /var/log/iptables.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20121021'
```

I'm flummoxed. How do I get logrotate to roll the file? I'm not 100% sure if I configured it correctly, but I don't know enough to be certain if that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a more effective solution would be to actually create a specific logrotate instance for iptables instead of adding it directly to your syslog logrotate instance.

Do this by:

```
$ touch /etc/logrotate.d/iptables
```

Now, configure the logrotation as you'd like, an example would be the following (You may find all options [HERE (logrotate.conf)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html):

```
$ vi iptables
/var/log/iptables.log {
missingok
notifempty
size 30k
create 0600 root root
postrotate
    /etc/rc.d/init.d/rsyslog restart ; sleep 5
endscript
}
```

This should provide the functionality you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks! That did exactly what I needed it to. Appreciate the helpful explanation!

Comment: You're quite welcome!

Comment: Restarting `rsyslog` after creating a new logrotate directive is unnecessary since `logrotate` is separate from `rsyslog` and called via `cron`. Also, `invoke-rc.d` appears not to work on CentOS 6.

Comment: Why the `touch ...`? And why the `sleep 5`?

Comment: @reflexiv, you probably want to use the same mechanism for the "log reload" as you have in the syslog file. I see a `kill -HUP ...` instead.